# Can't stop the service with error ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL

Tags: c++, winapi

I`m trying to write a windows service application, it is running just fine, but weird things happen when I try to stop it.

```
if (!ControlService(
    service,
    SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP,
    (LPSERVICE_STATUS)&ssp))
{
    //TODO: Log that can not send service a stop signal
    std::cout << ssp.dwCurrentState << std::endl;
    std::cout << GetLastError();
    CloseServiceHandle(service);
    CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
    return false;
}
```

That GetLastError() shows ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL(1061) error code, and [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-controlservice) says that this error can only occur when the process state is SERVICE_STOPPED, SERVICE_START_PENDING, or SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, but ssp.dwCurrentState is SERVICE_RUNNING. 
The same error occurs when I try to stop the service from Task Manager.

What can cause such behaviour?

Comment: problem in how service handle `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP`

Comment: The return value of `GetLastError` is meaningless at the point you are calling it. Please read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `SetServiceStatus()` tells the SCM what controls your service is prepared to receive. Likely your last call to `SetServiceStatus()` set `dwControlsAccepted` to 0 rather than a mask of reasonable values for a running service (`SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP` at the very least).

Update the call where you set `dwCurrentState` to `SERVICE_RUNNING` so that `dwControlsAccepted` includes `SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP`.