# Fail to stop kernel driver with STOP_PENDING

Tags: c, delphi, winapi, driver, kernel-mode

I have a kernel driver that enum and close all handles (of type "File") of files present in a specific folder, and [this](https://www.twblogs.net/a/5b7e18d12b7177683855467b) is the code of reference about how start to this goal. The kernel code is works very fine, but i have a small problem more specifically on moment to stop the driver. Then when execute the usermode code below *[STOP_PENDING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-controlservice)* is all that happens, and i'm not able close the usermode program. Already when i not execute the kernel code (to close handles), the driver can be stopped and deleted with success.

> PS: The usermode code not open any handle to target folder.

Some idea about reason to this strange behavior?

To better understanding here in this forum, i will post only relevant codes usermode/kernel mode.

**Usermode:**

```
function UninstallService(sMachine, sService: string): Boolean;
var
  schm, schs: SC_Handle;
  ss: TServiceStatus;
  dwChkP: dword;
begin
  Result := False;
  schm := OpenSCManagerW(PWideChar(sMachine), nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if schm > 0 then
  begin
    schs := OpenServiceW(schm, PWideChar(sService), _DELETE or SERVICE_STOP or SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    if schs > 0 then
    begin
      if (QueryServiceStatus(schs, ss)) then
      begin
        while (SERVICE_STOPPED <> ss.dwCurrentState) do
        begin
          ControlService(schs, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, ss);
          dwChkP := ss.dwCheckPoint;
          Sleep(ss.dwWaitHint);
          if (not QueryServiceStatus(schs, ss)) then
            Break;
          if (ss.dwCheckPoint < dwChkP) then
            Break;
        end;
      end;
      Result := DeleteService(schs);
      CloseServiceHandle(schs);
    end;
    CloseServiceHandle(schm);

    schm := OpenSCManagerW(PWideChar(sMachine), nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
    if schm > 0 then
    begin
      schs := OpenServiceW(schm, PWideChar(sService), _DELETE or SERVICE_STOP or SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
      if schs = 0 then
      begin
        if GetLastError = ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST then
        begin
          Writeln('Service not exists');
          Result := True;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        CloseServiceHandle(schs);
      end;
      CloseServiceHandle(schm);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**Kernel code:**

```
NTSTATUS DrvProcCreate(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;

    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS DrvProcClose(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;

    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

#define NT_DEVICE_NAME L"\\Device\\MyDrv"
#define DOS_DEVICE_NAME L"\\??\\MyDrv"

void DrvProcUnload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    UNICODE_STRING deviceLinkUnicodeString;
    NTSTATUS status;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&deviceLinkUnicodeString, DOS_DEVICE_NAME);

    status = IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&deviceLinkUnicodeString);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("IoDeleteSymbolicLink() error - 0x%X \n", status);
        return;
    }

    IoDeleteDevice(DriverObject->DeviceObject);

    DbgPrint("Goodbye from driver \n");
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    UNICODE_STRING deviceNameUnicodeString;
    UNICODE_STRING deviceLinkUnicodeString;
    PDEVICE_OBJECT deviceObject = NULL;
    NTSTATUS ntStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&deviceNameUnicodeString, NT_DEVICE_NAME);

    ntStatus = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, 0, &deviceNameUnicodeString, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &deviceObject);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus))
    {
        DbgPrint("IoCreateDevice() error - 0x%X \n", ntStatus);
        return ntStatus;
    }

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&deviceLinkUnicodeString, DOS_DEVICE_NAME);

    ntStatus = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&deviceLinkUnicodeString, &deviceNameUnicodeString);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus))
    {
        DbgPrint("IoCreateSymbolicLink() error - 0x%X \n", ntStatus);

        if (NULL != deviceObject)
        {
            IoDeleteDevice(deviceObject);
        }

        return ntStatus;
    }

    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = DrvProcCreate;
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = DrvProcUnload;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = DrvProcClose;

    DbgPrint("Hello from driver \n");

    return ntStatus;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

After first comment below, [`ControlService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-controlservice) returns:

**1061** - *ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL*, but in docs:

> Drivers do not accept control codes other than SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP and SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE.

---

**Edit 2:**

I tried unload with [PC Hunter](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/pc-hunter/) ARK (a famous chinese anti rootkit) and my driver was stopped with success. The implementation of [PC Hunter](http://www.xuetr.com/) to unload *.sys* module is something like [this](https://github.com/AzureGreen/ArkProtect/blob/5e4a3a9097a2d52c9f39773fab5597540afa7d51/ArkProtectDrv/DriverCore.c#L489). Why with Win32 api (ring3 - usermode) not works, someone know explain?

Comment: ControlService has a return result you should be checking followed by calling GetLastError to see the cause when it fails.

Comment: Does it fail with ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL the first or second time through the loop? Second time would be expected as if it worked the first the service should be SERVICE_STOP_PENDING. You would normally wait and give it time to stop maybe occasionally checking the status.

Comment: @Brian, *`"Does it fail with ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL the first or second time through the loop?"`*, all times. i belive that action of close handles is the reason, the service stay "busy" until next reboot. Like said on question, without execute the action *close file handles* all works fine. I think that this strange behavior no one still was able to understood/solve.

Comment: A related question mentions making sure set status doesn't mask out accepting the stop.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60803615/

Comment: *Why with Win32 api (ring3 - usermode) not works* - user mode api perfect works and unload driver if it can be unloaded at this time. user mode code not relevant to problem. your posted code for driver of course not relevant to real driver code too. so no sense post it. usual reason, why legacy driver can not be unloaded - not closed handles on some of it device. code in link - monstrous/ it can not work well and faster of all hung, which is lead to fail unload driver

Comment: @RbMm, yes, `QueryFileHandle()` (code in link) is flaw inside **while** loop, leaving some opened handles backward. Fixed! thank you by tip.